# VHDL : False Results in 4-Bit Adder and Subtractor

Tags: logic, vhdl, digital-logic

I want to make a 4-Bit Adder and Subtractor with VHDL
I have created 1-Bit Full-Adder , XOR Gate ( for Subtract ) and a 4-Bit Adder as shown below :

Full-Adder :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY FullAdder_1_Bit IS
  PORT(
    X, Y : IN STD_LOGIC;
    CIn  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    COut : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );
END FullAdder_1_Bit;

ARCHITECTURE Behavier OF FullAdder_1_Bit IS
BEGIN
  Sum <= X XOR Y XOR CIn;
  COut <= (X AND Y) OR (X AND CIn) OR (Y AND CIn);
END Behavier;
```

XOR Gate :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY XORGate IS
  PORT(
    X1, X2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Y : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END XORGate;

ARCHITECTURE Declare OF XORGate IS
BEGIN  
 Y <= X1 XOR X2;
END Declare;
```

4-Bit Adder :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY Adder_4_Bit IS
  PORT(
    A, B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    Mode : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    COut : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END Adder_4_Bit;

ARCHITECTURE Structure OF Adder_4_Bit IS
COMPONENT FullAdder_1_Bit IS
  PORT(
    X, Y : IN STD_LOGIC;
    CIn  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    COut : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT XORGate IS
  PORT(
    X1, X2 : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Y : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL COut_Temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL XB : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN  
  B_0 : XORGate PORT MAP(Mode, B(0), XB(0));
  B_1 : XORGate PORT MAP(Mode, B(1), XB(1));
  B_2 : XORGate PORT MAP(Mode, B(2), XB(2));
  B_3 : XORGate PORT MAP(Mode, B(3), XB(3));

  SUM_0 : FullAdder_1_Bit
  PORT MAP (A(0), XB(0), Mode, Sum(0), COut_Temp(0));

  SUM_1 : FullAdder_1_Bit
  PORT MAP (A(1), XB(1), COut_Temp(0), Sum(1), COut_Temp(1));

  SUM_2 : FullAdder_1_Bit
  PORT MAP (A(2), XB(2), COut_Temp(1), Sum(2), COut_Temp(2));

  SUM_3 : FullAdder_1_Bit
  PORT MAP (A(3), XB(3), COut_Temp(2), Sum(3), COut);  
END;
```

and in my Main Codes , i have used those ( like Test-Bench ! ) :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY Add_AND_Sub IS

END Add_AND_Sub;

ARCHITECTURE Declare OF Add_AND_Sub IS
COMPONENT Adder_4_Bit IS
  PORT(
    A, B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    Mode : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    COut : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL A, B : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL Mode : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL As, Bs, E, AVF : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL XA, XB, Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN 

 Add : Adder_4_Bit
 PORT MAP(XA, XB, Mode, Sum, E);

 PROCESS(A, B, Mode)
 BEGIN
  As <= A(4);
  Bs <= B(4);

  XA <= A(3 DOWNTO 0);
  XB <= B(3 DOWNTO 0);  

  CASE Mode IS
   WHEN '0' =>
     IF ((As XOR Bs) = '1') THEN                   
       Mode <= '1';
       XA <= Sum;       
       AVF <= '0';
       IF (E = '1') THEN
         IF (XA = "0000") THEN
           As <= '0';
         END IF;
       ELSE           
         XA <= (NOT XA) + "0001";
         As <= NOT As;
       END IF; 
     ELSE
       XA <= Sum;
     END IF;   

   WHEN '1' =>
     IF ((As XOR Bs) = '1') THEN              
       Mode <= '0';       
       XA <= Sum;       
       AVF <= E;        
     ELSE       
       AVF <= '0';
       XA <= Sum;
       IF (E = '1') THEN
         IF (XA = "0000") THEN
           As <= '0';
         END IF;
       ELSE
         XA <= (NOT XA) + "0001";
         As <= NOT As;
       END IF;      
     END IF;
   WHEN Others =>  
    --   
  END CASE;          
 END PROCESS; 

END Declare;
```

The main scenario is to Model this algorithm :

[image: Add_Sub_Algorithm]

but now i want to have output in XA and As

- I Should use registers shown in algorithm such as "E" and "AVF"

there is one question :

we know port maps are continuously connected , so when i change Mode Value , Result ( Sum ) must change , is it True ?!

I have tried this code but i cant get output in XA , and there is no True result for sum values , i know there is some problem in my main code ( Process ) , but i cant find problems

please check that codes and tell me what goes wrong !

**Edit** :

Im using ModelSim and its simulation for testing my code , first i force values of "A", "B" and "Mode" then run to get result and wave

thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Your testbench `add_and_sub` makes no assignments to it's `a` and `b`, they're default values are all 'U's.

What do you expect when your inputs to `adder_4_bit` are undefined?

Look at the  `not_table`, `or_table`, `and_table` and `xor_table` in the body of the std_logic_1164 package.

Also to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your readers need both expected and actual results.

If you're actually simulating the testbench I'd expect it consume no simulation time and after some number of delta cycles during initialization show `sum` and `e` chock full of 'U's.

I haven't personally modified your testbench to determine if your `adder_4_bit` works, but if you provide it with valid stimulus you can debug it. It can be helpful to consume simulation time and use different input values.

Adding a monitor process to `add_and_sub`:

```
 MONITOR:
     process (sum)
         function to_string(inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
             variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
             alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
         begin
             for i in input_str'range loop
                 image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
             end loop;
             -- report "image_str = " & image_str;
             return image_str;
         end;
     begin
         report "sum = " & to_string(sum);
     end process;
```

gives:

> fourbitadder.vhdl:174:10:@0ms:(report note): sum = uuuu

one event on `sum`.

Add a process to cause events on `a` and 'b`:

```
STIMULUS:
     process
     begin
         a <= "00000" after 10 ns;
         b <= "00000" after 10 ns;
         wait for 20 ns;
         wait;
     end process;
```

and we get:

[image: add_and_sub.png]
*(clickable)*

We find we get an event on `a` and `b` but `sum` didn't change.

And the reason why is apparent in the case statement in the process. The default value of mode is 'U', and the case statement has choices for `0`, `1` and:

```
   when others =>  
    --   
  end case;
```

And the others choice results in no new value in `mode`.

Why nothing works can be discovered by reading the source of the body for package std_logic_1164, the xor_table, and_table, or_table. With `mode = 'U'` all your combinatorial outputs will be 'U'.

And to fix this you can assign a default value to `mode` where it is declared in the testbench:

```
signal mode : std_logic := '0';
```

With `mode` defined as a valid choice resulting in some action we note `xa` is now never defined causing the same issue:

[image]
*(clickable)*

And this is a problem in the process:

```
 process(a, b, mode)
 begin
  as <= a(4);
  bs <= b(4);

  xa <= a(3 downto 0);
  xb <= b(3 downto 0);  

  case mode is
   when '0' =>
     if ((as xor bs) = '1') then                   
       mode <= '1';
       xa <= sum;       
       avf <= '0';
       if (e = '1') then
         if (xa = "0000") then
           as <= '0';
         end if;
       else           
         xa <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(not xa) + unsigned'("0001"));
         as <= not as;
       end if; 
     else
       xa <= sum;
     end if;   

   when '1' =>
     if ((as xor bs) = '1') then              
       mode <= '0';       
       xa <= sum;       
       avf <= e;        
     else       
       avf <= '0';
       xa <= sum;
       if (e = '1') then
         if (xa = "0000") then
           as <= '0';
         end if;
       else
         xa <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(not xa) + unsigned'("0001"));
         as <= not as;
       end if;      
     end if;
   when others =>  
    --   
  end case;
```

Notice there are three places where `xa` is assigned, with no simulation time between them.  There's only one projected output waveform value for any simulation time. A later assignment in the same process will result in the later value being assigned, in this case `sum`, which is all 'U's.

So how do you solve this conundrum?  There are two possibilities. First you could not try and do algorithmic stimulus generation, assigning input to `add` explicitly with wait statements between successive assignments of different values. You can also insert delays between successive assignments to the same signal in the existing process, which requires a substantial re-write.

On a positive note the `adder_4_bit` and `full_adder_1bit` look like they should work. The problem appears to be all in the testbench.

Comment: Thanks, I forget to say that Im using ModelSim and i use its simulation for testing my code , first i Force values of "A" , "B" , and "Mode" then run it to get result and wave , but for sum values result is incorrect , and as you say my process have problem; 
" So how do you solve this conundrum? There are two possibilities " : 
Is it possible to give me an example ?

Comment: I know i should have a control unit for each sequence of algorithm; for example each sequence done with a component and a control bit on it
but Im not sure how to do that !

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes

I made a ALU unit as :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY ALU IS
  PORT(
    --Clk  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    A, B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
    Sel  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    AOut : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
    AsO  : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END ALU;

ARCHITECTURE Declare OF ALU IS
COMPONENT Adder_4_Bit IS
  PORT(
    A, B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    Mode : IN STD_LOGIC;
    Sum  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    COut : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL As, Bs, E, AVF : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL XA, XB, Sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL Mode : STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN  

 Add : Adder_4_Bit
 PORT MAP(XA, XB, Mode, Sum, E);  

 PROCESS
 BEGIN

 As <= A(4);
 Bs <= B(4);

 XA <= A(3 DOWNTO 0);
 XB <= B(3 DOWNTO 0);  

  CASE Sel IS
   WHEN '0' =>
     IF ((As XOR Bs) = '1') THEN                  
       Mode <= '1';              
       AVF <= '0';
       WAIT ON Sum;
       IF (E = '1') THEN
         IF (Sum = "0000") THEN
           As <= '0';
         END IF;
       ELSE          
         Sum <= (NOT Sum) + "0001";
         As <= NOT As;
       END IF;
     ELSE
       Mode <= '0';
       WAIT ON Sum;
     END IF;

     AOut <= Sum;
     AsO  <= As;  

   WHEN '1' =>
     IF ((As XOR Bs) = '1') THEN              
       Mode <= '0';
       WAIT ON Sum;                    
       AVF <= E;        
     ELSE      
       Mode <= '1';
       WAIT ON Sum;
       AVF <= '0';
       IF (E = '1') THEN
         IF (Sum = "0000") THEN
           As <= '0';
         END IF;
       ELSE
         Sum <= (NOT Sum) + "0001";
         As <= NOT As;
       END IF;      
     END IF;
     AOut <= Sum;
     AsO  <= As;
   WHEN Others =>  
    --  
  END CASE;

 END PROCESS;

END Declare;
```

and A Test Bench like this :

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY ALU_Test_Bench IS

END ALU_Test_Bench;

ARCHITECTURE Declare OF ALU_Test_Bench IS
COMPONENT ALU IS
  PORT(
    --Clk  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    A, B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
    Sel  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    AOut : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
    AsO  : OUT STD_LOGIC
  );  
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL Xs, S : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL X, Y, O : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN

  ALU_PM : ALU PORT MAP(X, Y, S, O, Xs);

  Main_Process : PROCESS
  BEGIN      
   WAIT FOR 100 ns;  
   X <= "00010";
   Y <= "11011";

   S <= '0';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;
   S <= '1';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;

   WAIT FOR 100 ns;  
   X <= "01110";
   Y <= "10011";

   S <= '0';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;
   S <= '1';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;

   WAIT FOR 100 ns;  
   X <= "10011";
   Y <= "11111";

   S <= '0';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;
   S <= '1';
   WAIT FOR 30 ns;

  END PROCESS;

END Declare;
```

As i say , i want to model the algorithm i posted in first post

there is some problem ...

for example when i simulate and run test bench , there is no output value in O and Xs !

I know the problem is in ALU and Test Bench

I changed ALU many times and tested many ways but all times some things goes wrong !

If you want to code that algorithm , which units you will create or at all what will you create ?! and how will you code that ?!

thanks for your help ...